# How to generate a PDF with SimplePDF in Swift

Tags: swift, pdf, pdf-generation

I've got a problem regarding how to use SimplePDF.

I would like to export a PDF file from my application when I press a simple UIButton.

Now I try to use the standard code give by SimplePDF but I still have a problem :

The code :

```
let a4PaperSize = CGSize(width: 210, height: 297)
    let pdf = SimplePDF(pageSize: a4PaperSize)

    pdf.setContentAlignment(.center)

    // add logo image
    let logoImage = UIImage(named:"train-icon180.png")!
    pdf.addImage(logoImage)

    // [...]

    // Generate PDF data and save to a local file.
    // Here is where I've got a problem 
    if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {

        let fileName = "\(ReceptionOuvertureLigne).pdf"
        let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + fileName

        let pdfData = pdf.generatePDFdata()
        do{
            try pdfData.writeToFile(documentsFileName, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
            print("\nThe generated pdf can be found at:")
            print("\n\t\(documentsFileName)\n")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
```

In fact the line : `try pdfData.writeToFile(documentsFileName, options: .DataWritingAtomic)` in the PDF generating part result by an error :

`Value of type 'Data' has no member 'writeToFile'`

I don't know how to solve it ...

Comment: Can you upload your code somewhere and put the link here?

Comment: I've use this tutorial code : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nrewik/SimplePDF/v3.0.0/ExampleCode.swift

Comment: I don't even know a guy named `generatePDFdata()`.

Comment: Which swift version are you using? it works fine with swift 4 for me.

Comment: Swift 4 also ...